# Problem using form runat=server with master pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I have a master page with two `ContentPlaceHolders`.

I have a default page.aspx which uses this master page.

In the default page one `ContentHolder` has a `TreeView` and the other has a `GridView`.

Now i need to display both of them together and both require `<form runat="server">`.

But the issue is that i cant have two instances of `<form runat="server">` in a single page.

I tried putting `<form runat="server">` on the master page but then the `TreeView`and `GridView` functionality stops working.....

Please help me as to what can i do to solve this.

Page File:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="GridViewPg1.aspx.cs" Inherits="GridViewPg1" %>

<%@ Register assembly="obout_Grid_NET" namespace="Obout.Grid" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">   
   <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical">

   <a style="color: #000000; font-weight: bold;">SumooHServer</a>
       <p>&nbsp;<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [MachineGroupName], [MachineGroupID] FROM [MachineGroups]">
       </asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
           SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [PolicyID], [PolicyName] FROM [Policies]">
       </asp:SqlDataSource>
       <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView2" runat="server" 
           ontreenodepopulate="TreeView2_TreeNodePopulate">
           <Nodes>
               <asp:TreeNode NavigateUrl="~/GridViewPg1.aspx" PopulateOnDemand="True" 
                   Text="Machine Group" Value="Machine Group"></asp:TreeNode>
           </Nodes>
       </asp:TreeView>
       <asp:TreeView ID="TreeView3" runat="server" 
           ontreenodepopulate="TreeView3_TreeNodePopulate">
           <Nodes>
               <asp:TreeNode PopulateOnDemand="True" Text="Policies" Value="Policies">
               </asp:TreeNode>
           </Nodes>
       </asp:TreeView>
       </p></asp:Panel>
</form>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">

<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" ScrollBars="None" Width="100%">
    <cc1:Grid ID="Grid1" runat="server" AllowFiltering="True" 
    AllowGrouping="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3">
    </cc1:Grid>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [MachineGroups]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Panel>

</asp:Content>
```

Masterpage file:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>SumooH</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header" 
          style="border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-color: #0000FF; border-bottom-width: medium">
    </div>

     <div id="left-content" 
          style="border-right: thin ridge #000000; top: 104px;">

          <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="content-inner">


        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>


      </div>
   <div id="footer">
        <p>&nbsp;</p> 
   </div>
     </div>


   </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem; this is unintelligible

Comment: The problem is i cannot get the treeview and gridview are not working when displayed together

Comment: now when i run this i gives me an error saying gridview need form runat server. and if i put it it give an error sayig there cant be 2 runat servers.

Comment: Remove the Obout Grid and its associated code and see what happens. I'm curious as to whether or not that's actually the root issue -- maybe it's incompatible with master pages?

Comment: if i remove that the the page runs and so does the treeview...
Even if i put a normal grid the error is there

Comment: When the Obout grid is removed, but the master page is still present, and the master page is the only place there is `<form runat="server">`, the page works? But if you add any other type of gridview, then it fails? Did I read that correctly? Are you sure you're pulling both the opening *and* closing tags for `form` out of the sub-page?

Comment: I have posted the master page file... as you can see there is no form runat server there.. if i place a form runat server there then the collapse and expand functionality stops working and the sorting and paging property of gridview stops working.. as if that page becomes static.

Answer (score 6):

You say that the TreeView and GridView functionality "stops working" when the `<form runat="server">` is in the master page -- but if doing two forms (one in the master, one in the page using the master) doesn't work, then technically it's not working either way.

The correct idiom for ASP.NET 2.0+ using master pages is to place the form tag in the master page. The pages using the master, if wired up correctly, will not need form tags -- they will get the tag from their master. The web app I just deployed this morning worked that way. :)

I'm guessing that there's actually a code issue buried in the page itself causing the TreeView and GridView to not function once the form tags are implemented correctly.

**EDIT**

To be clear, the master page must have `<form runat="server">`, all of the other controls & HTML needed, the placeholders, and a closing `</form>` tag.

The pages using the master cannot have any `<form runat="server">` tags at all, and especially not a closing `</form>` tag.

Done this way, there should be no problems.

Comment: i have posted the .aspx page if u want i can post the masterpage too, if that helps in anyway... thanks

Comment: i tried that but as i told you the treeview control and the gridviewcontrol functionality stops working..... 
This why i am confused as to what to do...

Comment: But only the gridview? The treeview works? I think you still have a `</form>` in the page somewhere if that's the case. Please edit your post to show the code you're changing it to, where form is in the master and there are no form tags in the child ... Then we can troubleshoot more effectively.

Answer (score 2):

Your master page should contain the form element, with the closing element at the bottom of it.

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>SumooH</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server" />
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Your content pages should not contain any form elements for your purposes.

Comment: I did the same thing first, but when i do this the gridview and treeview functionality stops working. why does that happen... and when i put the form in masterpage i remove the form from all other pages...

Comment: I think you may have something else going on then.